Palladium coupling reactions and purification
I tried to synthesize 2-(6-fluoropyridin-3-yl) acetic acid from 5-(Chloromethyl)-2-fluoropyridine using Pd(OAc)2/PPh3 catalyst,Na2CO3 and DCC. I eluted my product on TLC with Ethyl acetate/hexane/acetic acid with a 1:4:1 ratio and I saw a spot for my compound. I extracted my compound with water and chloroform to remove any salts and then did silica chromatography to remove Pd. But when I took the NMR of the compound I could not see any peaks in the aromatic range for the pyridine ring, and it seems my compound has decomposed. I cannot figure out where is the problem. Does anyone have any clue to help with this issue?

Did you recheck by TLC after the CHCl3/water extraction including checking the aq phase?

Yes, I did. The spot was the same for the organic phase and no spot for the aqueous phase

If you have a reference compound, you could try to make a "co-spot", meaning that you put a droplet of your product and the ref. compound at the same spot as well as their individual spots and watch whether the signal belongs to the same compound.

Did you see the compound spot by TLC in the column fractions?

Have you considered taking your starting material and reacting it with KCN in DMF then hydrolysing?
